# From <center> to center in CSS

Tags: html, css, center

How to do from `<center>` tag in

> HTML5

to center in

> CSS3

?

Comment: `text-align: center`

Comment: But don't working.

Comment: For block-level elements, you can provide a width and then set `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`.

Comment: Thanks, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

```
.someClass, #someId {
    text-align: center;
}
```

For a more appropriate fix please provide your specific code.